# Dynamic height allocation for divs

Tags: html, css

I have an outer div with a 75% height. I have an inner scrollable div A and another inner scrollable div B. 
div B can be remove dynamically and it has a variable height with max-height.
I want div A to automatically adjust its height based on div B.

```
#outer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 200px;
}

#dynamic-content {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 44px;
}
```

I’m looking for a pure css approach

Here’s a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6tr081hb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a `flex` container, this way you can have a fixed height for the dynamic-content and an adjustable height for the content by setting the `flex` property to `1`.

Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tr081hb/1/).

I also removed absolute positioning for the contents and added a `padding` to the `outer` div.